# adb does not see devices connected to Apple Thunderbolt Cinema Display

Tags: android, macos, adb

If I plug my android devices directly into the usb port of my Macbook Pro, "adb devices" lists them properly.

However, if I instead plug them into the USB ports on my display (which is connected to my macbook via thunderbolt), "adb devices" reports no devices attached.

Is there a way to get adb to see devices that are connected to my display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be intermittent and may be related to if the laptop goes to sleep.  Unplugging the display from the macbook, waiting for the macbook to sleep or refresh display, then plugging it back in seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference. I've tested a variety of devices and they are recognized if they are connected to the display's USB ports.
Check your cables.

Comment: exact same cable in both cases.  other usb devices are recognized when plugged in to the display.

Comment: well, the problem seems to have mysteriously gone away.  Leaving this up for posterity in case the problem re-presents or anyone else runs into the same issue in the future